# imutils VideoStream(src=0) return VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument in raspberry pi

Tags: camera, opencv, python-3, webcam, pi-4

I am only doing a simple code in my Raspberry Pi 4:

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream

# initialize the video streams and allow them to warmup
print("[INFO] starting cameras...")
webcam = VideoStream(src=0).start()
```

I can run this code without any problem with raspberry pi camera but get error with my Logitech C310 webcam.

The error is: `VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument`

The camera works perfectly when used with `fswebcam` in the terminal. I also tried using it with online webcam test, and it works. My only problem is, the camera can't be used with my python code. I also tried using it with opencv and it return `None`.

Hardware: Raspberry Pi 4 4GB

OS: Raspbian Buster

Hope anyone can help, thank you.

Comment: Related: [Raspberry Pi4 Error while using 2 USB cameras, VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/105358/33476).

Answer (score 0):

Running the following commands have resolved the issue for me:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=10000 quirks=0x80
```

Comment: Can you also explain what that does?

Comment: Bill Armstrong has already explained  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/105788/112892