# Raspberry Pi4 Error while using 2 USB cameras, VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument

Tags: usb, camera, opencv, pi-4

I'm using Python OpenCV to read from 2 USB webcams on a Raspberry Pi4. If I'm using either of the camera individually they work fine. 
As soon as I initialize both cameras in the script as following:

```
import cv2
cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0);
cap0.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap0.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(2);
cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while True:
        ret0, frame1 = cap0.read()
        ret1, frame2 = cap1.read()

        print('Retval cap0: ' ,ret0)
        print('Retval cap1: ', ret1)

        if ret0:
                cv2.imshow('frame1', frame1)
        if ret1:
                cv2.imshow('frame2', frame2)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                break

cap0.release()
cap1.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get this ouput:

```
select timeout
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable
Retval cap0:  True
Retval cap1:  False
VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
Retval cap0:  True
Retval cap1:  False
VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument
...
```

If I use 640x480 resolution it seems to work but I would need the HD resolution.
It didn't help to add a deleay between the read steps.
Using the Rpi3 Model B+ (Raspian Strech) I can run the script properly, the VIDIOC Error appeard only on Rpi4 (Raspian Buster).

Comment: This also occurs with one USB camera attached.  I think it is a change between the July 10th release of Buster and the September 26th release (untested for the moment).  I had the above script running on the 7/10 release, but have the same `VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable` error on 9/26 release.  This also is an issue on `pygame` for video capture, but not for very slow image capture (?).

Comment: I can confirm also on RPi4 Raspian/Buster with 2 USB cameras. same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to narrow this down to a Kernel issue.  I do think there is something that has been updated that is causing the problem since the 7/10 release...

If you look at a list (`lsmod`) of your Kernal modules you see one called `uncvideo` - this is the problem item.  Start by removing it:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rmmod uvcvideo
```

Then you can read the module with some extended longer no response triggers.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

The `nodrop=1` makes sure that even corrupt frames get delivered.  This will help by putting a bad frame upfront to get the process going.  See source [here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/238#issuecomment-14836438).

The `timeout` is obvious - it just extends the no response trigger.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715209/select-timeout-error-in-ubuntu-opencv?answertab=active#tab-top).

The `quirks` parameter is a bit of a mystery to me - but there is some documentation [here](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/faq/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25619309/how-do-i-enable-the-uvc-quirk-fix-bandwidth-quirk-in-linux-uvc-driver).  The second one is where I came up with the 0x80 value - but you'll see that there appears to be a lot of options (640 adds a baud rate adjustment).

As a final note, with these modifications, I got the OpenCV 4.0.0 installed and running on Python 3.7.3.  The whole thing is running on a Raspi 4 x 4gb.  The performance is still way too slow - so more work needed here.

Comment: Unfortunately I was still not able to run the above script properly after using the suggested modifications. (Buster 9/26 release, OpenCV 3.4.5 and Python 3.7.3)

Comment: Yes - I had to roll back to Buster 7/10 release to get it to work. Although I’m using a different OpenCV version (4.0.0) which maybe has an impact.

Comment: So far I tried it with Buster 7/10 release and OpenCV 4.1.0 which was unsuccessfull. However I didn't manage to install OpenCV 4.0.0 yet.

Comment: Even in the suggested configuration, Buster 7/10 release, OpenCV 4.0.0 and Python 3.7.3 I was not sucessfull in running the code with 2 cams. Further investigation showed, that if I'm using this configuration in combination with a Rpi 3B+ the Error messages didn't appear and all retval were all shown as True. To test that I inserted the same micro SD card in the Pi4 and Pi3. It seems as my Rpi4 might be the problem.

Comment: I have a couple of Raspi 3s laying around. I’ll also give that a try - the FPS on the 4 (even though I can get it to work) makes it ineffective.  Hope it’s fixable.

Comment: Just to clarify - I’ve been working with three Raspi 4s and all have the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that there are some limitations in the main USB camera driver `uvc`, or your CPU/GPU's processing power for that matter, where running multiple uncompressed camera streams will just ... hang. [see](https://superuser.com/questions/431759/using-multiple-usb-webcams-in-linux)

So, since OpenCV uses `uvc` to read the USB camera stream in Linux and that `cv2.VideoCapture` **might default** to some uncompressed stream like **YUYV**, we need to change the stream format into something like **MJPG** , depending if it is supported by the camera, likewise:

```
import cv2

#first camera src
cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0); 
# set the format into MJPG in the FourCC format 
cap0.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))

#same for camera 2
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(2);
cap1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'))
```

To check what streams are supported by your camera run:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --list-formats
```

or for more details

```
$ luvcview -d /dev/video0 -L
```