# Raspberry Pi4 error capturing image with OpenCV, image comes half green

Tags: raspbian, opencv, webcam

I am using a common [logitech webcam](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c270) with OpenCV. When I was using my RPI3 I had no trouble, but I wanted to improve my system so I bought a RPI4.

Upon setting up my system with RPI4 using raspian buster I've started getting:

```
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

After I saw this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/105358/raspberry-pi4-error-while-using-2-usb-cameras-vidioc-qbuf-invalid-argument) here I tried:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rmmod uvcvideo
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

Now my image comes like this:

[image: Half green image]

The upper part of the image is ok, it's night time and it is pointing to my backyard, however I don't know how to solve the green part problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your webcam device is in [this list](http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/) in `Supported device` : `Device works` state for `046d:0825 Logitech HD Webcam C270`, can you put your dmesg or syslog output ?

Comment: How did you install opencv?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it!!!

This is really needed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo rmmod uvcvideo
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe uvcvideo nodrop=1 timeout=5000 quirks=0x80
```

But also, I had to set my webcam FPS prop to a low value.

```
0. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC Current position of the video file in milliseconds.
1. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES 0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next.
2. CV_CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO Relative position of the video file
3. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH Width of the frames in the video stream.
4. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT Height of the frames in the video stream.
5. CV_CAP_PROP_FPS Frame rate.
6. CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC 4-character code of codec.
7. CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT Number of frames in the video file.
8. CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT Format of the Mat objects returned by retrieve() .
9. CV_CAP_PROP_MODE Backend-specific value indicating the current capture mode.
10. CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS Brightness of the image (only for cameras).
11. CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST Contrast of the image (only for cameras).
12. CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION Saturation of the image (only for cameras).
13. CV_CAP_PROP_HUE Hue of the image (only for cameras).
14. CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN Gain of the image (only for cameras).
15. CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE Exposure (only for cameras).
16. CV_CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB Boolean flags indicating whether images should be converted to RGB.
17. CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE Currently unsupported
18. CV_CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION Rectification
```

Before starting to read the cam just do:

```
cam.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 10)
```

All set! :)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: There's no checkmark to accept the answer, don't know what to do :(

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen that you have just made the answer. Please wait 48 hours, then it should be possible to accept an own answer.

Comment: It´s been a month already...

Comment: Seems you are using two accounts with the same name. Please use the same account you have made the question, the account with 21 reputation. Only the owner of a question can accept answers, of course.